# 13:68 'end' expected near '<eof>'

Tags: lua

Im trying to fix a script and I have no idea how to script if anyone can help me out that'd be great my issue is at the last line, line 13 has an error and it says

> [13:68] 'end' expected near '<eof>'

```lua
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
mouse.KeyDown:connect(function(key)
if key == "t" then
Wag = Instance.new("Sound")
Wag.SoundId = "rbxassetid://4621721605"
Wag.Parent = game.Lighting
Wag.Volume = 10
Wag:Play()
wait(2.3)
game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:BreakJoints()
wait(2)
game.Players.LocalPlayer:Kick("test.")
```

Comment: The error message I get is `'end' expected (to close 'if' at line 4) near <eof>`, which is quite clear.

Answer (score 2):

The error is exactly what it's telling you: Lua expects to find a `end` to close the `if` on the fourth line but instead the file just ends.

Comment: there is also a missing `)` to close connect

Comment: that comes after the `end` though ;)

Comment: hey so the fix you gave me worked but the issue Im having now is that the specific key that I want it to activate on is "T" and it seems to be activing on whatever key I press.